# AngularJS - validation not based on form element

Tags: angularjs, validation

Is there a way to inject some validation - custom or otherwise - that isn't tied to a form element? Like - validate that some condition is met, but have it work with standard AngularJS validation?

*Update:*

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a form contains a list of sections. Each section is controlled by a checkbox, and the section will display (via an ng-if) when the checkbox is checked.

Within each section, there's an opportunity for an item to be selected via a popup modal that is activated by a button click. Until an item is selected for that section, the form needs to be invalid. Once an item is selected *for each selection that is checked*, then the form needs to be valid.

I have a button at the bottom of the form with an ng-disabled="frm.$invalid". I want that to stay disabled until each section that has been checked contains an item that was selected via the modal.

*Update 2:*

Here's some example code:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="frm" novalidate>
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" required/>

  <div ng-repeat="orderItem in orderItems">
    <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" ng-model="orderItem.selected"/>
    <div ng-if="orderItem.selected">
      ... bunch of form fields
      <button ng-click="openExchangeSelectionModal(orderItem)">Select Item</button>
      <div ng-show="orderItem.exchange_item">
        Selected Item: {{orderItem.exchange_item.name}} - ${{orderItem.exchange_item.price | number: 2}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button ng-disabled="frm.$invalid" ng-click="submitOrder">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: are you trying to validate before the modal closes? It sounds like you are looking for a directive. something like `<div my-validator></div>` and in the directive you can check the innerHTML or if put onto an <input> you can check the value

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically? Without some code, it will not be so easy for us to help you.

Comment: @Ero: I want it to validate after the modal closes

Comment: @lealceldeiro: I want to validate that an item was elected in the modal before allowing the form to be submitted. The submit button has ng-disabled="frm.$invalid" on it - so I'm hoping for the form to be invalid unless an item has been selected. I'll update the question to reflect what I'm trying to do.

Comment: could you post some of the code? the form with one of the mentioned sections and the submit button should be enough.

Comment: @Ero: updated - it's demo code but gives you the idea, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if the form is valid won't help you in this case since there is no required input that's not being filled.
What I would recommend is that the disable button would call a function that makes some logic about the number of check boxes expanded and the number of selected items and returns the buttons state (true for active otherwise false)

Let's take the example code you put up:

```
//some html tags...

  <button ng-disabled="checkValid()" ng-click="submitOrder">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Notice that I changed the frm.$invalid to checkValid function, which is a function that is defined on your controller and can perform any logic you want to determine rather show your submit button or not.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure the form is invalid until the item has been selected?

Comment: That logic needs to be implemented in the "checkValid" function

Comment: Gotcha - so no way using native AngularJS?

Comment: There is no custom native validation, that's why it's custom :) calling a function from the controller I think will serve what you need best

Comment: I truly recommend to transfer the logic into a controller function, your solution doesn't sound like best practice at all